# Tabs open according to links on sub menu

Tags: html, tabs, menuitem, submenu

In my main navigation bar there is a menu named `category & item` and it has two submenus which names are `category` and `item` respectively. I have only one page to display these two section.

My page is category_item.php and it has two different tabs to display each sections. In this case it is `category` and `item`.

So my problem is I need to open `category` and `item` tab when clicking on `category` and `item` links on the submenu.

**UPDATE -**

This is code from main navigation bar

```
<li class="current">
    <a>Category & Item</a>
        <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu-link">
                <a href="">Category</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-link current">
                <a href="">Item</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

This is from category_item.php page

```
<div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">My Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">My Items</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="tabs-1" class="tabs3">
    my stuff...
</div>

<div id="tabs-21" class="tabs3">
    my stuff...
</div>
```

Can I know is it possible to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample code?

Comment: How do your tabs look like?

Comment: @ErminDedovic I updated my question. Did you check it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Javascript. Just toggle property `display` of that class from `none` to `block` and vice versa.
If you are using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cat_link').click(function() {
        $('#tabs-1').hide();
        $('#tabs-2').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('#item_link').click(function() {
        $('#tabs-2').hide();
        $('#tabs-1').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

You also have [jQuery-UI widget tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

If you are using pure javascript, you can do it like this ([reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom3.shtml)):

```
function hideshow(which){
    if (!document.getElementById)
        return
    if (which.style.visibility=="visible")
        which.style.display="hidden"
    else
        which.style.display="visible"
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how can I figure out this using jquery?

Comment: Sorry, you need to add ids to this
<a href="" id="cat_link">Category</a>
<a href="" id="item_link">Item</a>

Comment: this coding working only in one tab. not changing between tabs

Comment: changing content but not changing tabs according to contents.